# How to see overlapped part of previous ciricle in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transparency

When i draw one circle above another, they overlap and i an not able to see the ovelapping part of below circle. I want to see both the circles

Comment: set the fill color of the top circle to "none"- or reduce the opacity of the fill on the top circle in the appearance panel- or select the underneath circle and you will be able to see the selection highlight through the fill of the top circle

Answer (score 0):

As commented, remove the fill color from both circles, just to make sure.

Another option, depending on what you plan on doing next, is to set both circles to 'Multiply'.